# I'm trying to change the localstorage expiration time from forever to 24 hours

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have implemented a dialogue which shows whenever a user access the website. However, I want the dialogue to reappear after 24 hours if someone accesses the site clicking on the cookie. Unfortunately, I spent a lot of time researching and I haven't found any solution which applies to my scenario. Below is the code I'm trying to modify,

```
var is_dialogue = window.localStorage.getItem("dialogue");
if (is_dialogue != 'false') {
    var today = new Date();
    var hours = today.getHours();
    dialogue = new Dialogue();
    dialogue.setHtmlMessage(string('dialogue-heading'));
    dialogue.addHtmlDetail(string('dialogue-detail'));

    if (((today.getHours() + 24) >= 24) || ((today.getHours() + 24) <= 48))
       localStorage.setItem("dialogue", "true");
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be storing the last accessed time in `localStorage` and be comparing that date/time against the current date/time and see if there is a <= 24 hour diffference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage has no expiration time, but you can compare timestamps:

```
function moreThanOneDayAgo(date) {
    const DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    const dayAgo = Date.now() - DAY;

    return date < dayAgo;
}

var is_dialogue = localStorage.getItem("dialogue");
if (is_dialogue === null || moreThanOneDayAgo(is_dialogue)) {
    dialogue = new Dialogue();
    dialogue.setHtmlMessage(string('dialogue-heading'));
    dialogue.addHtmlDetail(string('dialogue-detail'));

    localStorage.setItem("dialogue", Date.now());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Was struggling with this whole day..

Answer (score 1):

I would use [date-fns/differenceInHours](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/differenceInHours) or a similar library, but it's up to you:)

In a global script:

```
const checkTimestamp = (timestamp) => {
 return differenceInHours(new Date(), timestamp) > 24;
}

const isUserConsentExpired = () => {
  const timestamp = localStorage.getItem(***);
  return timestamp
   ? checkTimestamp(timestamp)
   : false
}

window.onload(() => {
  if(!isUserConsentExpired) {
    return;
}

... open cookie dialog...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the cookie, against localStorage, because there the expiration is solved, you don't have to code for this feature.
Here is an example below!

And I found a post about the differences between localSotrage and cookie, if you would like to know more about this topic.

[Cookies vs. LocalStorage: What’s the difference?](https://medium.com/swlh/cookies-vs-localstorage-whats-the-difference-d99f0eb09b44)

```js
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, exDays) {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + exDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  let expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${cookieValue};${expires};path=/`;
}

setCookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", 30)
```

Comment: The OP is asking about `localStorage`, not cookies.

Comment: Okay but the cookie has expiration property, the local storage doesnt. If you want to check the expiration, then you should save not only a true or false, but the date and time of last saving. Then you can compare the timestam of save and current time! Please remove the -1. My solution is correct! The qustion is maybe wrong! :)

Comment: Your solution may "work", but not the way the OP wants to have it work, so it's not correct. The question is certainly not wrong as it's the OPs requirement, not  yours.

Comment: Not to mention that good answers on SO are more than just "Try this one!" with a code dump. They explain their reasoning and how the code works. They may often include reinforcing links. This is not a good answer.

Comment: Okay I can accept it! If somebody would like to go on the hard way, we have to help him/her to find that way! Please paul35 give +1 to my solution if you like it! ? :D

Comment: Okay, I would do that, thanks. Sorry I am new here. But I like this platform. :) I am happy to be here!

Comment: And we're happy to have you. But please know and follow our [guidelines for answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) questions. By the way, many would say that the `localStorage` solution is the easier way. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245569/discussion-between-exphoenee-and-scott-marcus).